# html iframe and vspace and hspace atribute

Tags: html

Okay, I have an exam on friday on html basics, the only problem I still have is that the hspace and vspace attribute in combination with an iframe, it just does not give me space between the iframe and the tekst next to it... if it try it with an image it works super. I will give an example.

`<img src="image.jpg" align="left" hspace="10">` gives me 10 pixels of space
`<iframe src="something.html" align="left" hspace="10">` gives me an ifram to the left to a text (what is what I want) but it does not give me the 10 px of whitespace

we are nonly alowed to use html in this test. Can somebody please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `iframe` element never had `hspace` and `vspace` attributes, or anything like that, in any specification or implementation.

If you need to do things with HTML alone, no CSS allowed, presumably as an odd exercise, then you need to resort to rather ugly tricks. To set spacing on *all* sides of an `iframe` element, you could use a single-cell table with cell padding set:

```html
<table cellpadding="10" align="left"><tr>
  <td><iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
</table>
Hello world!
```

But if you need spacing e.g. only to the right of the `iframe` element, you can use a different table trick, with a 10px wide cell between it and the text. Note that this affects the overall layout, since now you have the stuff in a table.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr valign="top">
  <td><iframe src="about:blank"></iframe></td>
  <td width="10"></td>
  <td>Hello world!</td>
</table>
```